# Angular2 Difference between @angular/ and angular2/ imports

Tags: angular

While looking at some Angular2 project, I see two different kind of imports :
some are starting with `@angular/` like `@angular/core` by instance, and some others with `angular2` (`angular2/core`).

What's the difference ? Where does that come from ?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`@angular` is for release candidate (RC) versions and `angular2` for beta versions. There was a renaming between these versions (beta and RC)...

Answer (score 0):

**The Difference**

- angular2/core is **Beta**
- @angular/core  is **Going to be a Final release**